# How to extract day and month from a pandas data_frame which is in the format 4/23/20?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Can you help me out in extracting date and month from the dataset which is having date in the format of 4/23/16?

actually `pd.to_datetime("4/23/16",format="%m/%d/%Y").dt.day` doesn't work as the Year is 16 not 2016
is there any other way to extract date and month.
And if I use the same format for 4/23/16 ,I'm getting this kind of error

```
ValueError: time data '2/12/20' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y' (match)
```

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Two digit years are parsed by lower-case `%y` - see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes). Voting to close because of typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. Note %Y is for the full year while %y is for short year format

```
pd.to_datetime("4/23/16",format="%m/%d/%y").day
```

Comment: by the way, `pd.to_datetime("4/23/16")` works out-of-the-box since month-day-year is the standard sequence assumed by pd.to_datetime